# JPA query parameter IN or IS NULL

Tags: sql, jpa

I have an issue with this simple query :

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cat c WHERE c.id IN (:idCat) OR :idCat IS NULL")
List<Cat> getAllCatWithOrWithoutId(@Param("idCat")List<String> idCat);
```

Which queried in a list, or, if the id is not mentionned, select all cats in table (idCat is optional actually).
It seems working when it's an "=" operator instead of IN but when I run the query I have the error message is : "invalid relational operator".
Even if I try with a native query.
I tried to replace idCat value by single value (it worked), or by null (it worked too), but not when I put several values.

Is it something wrong in syntax or is it simply impossible with an IN statement?

Comment: it is not clear from your question the specific cases you tested and failed. Did you use idCat as an individual item? As a list? As null? In which of these cases dit it fail? Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I updated my post to be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide a filled list, your second part of the query (*OR :idCat IS NULL*) is translated to a list of values to compare to "*IS NULL*".

As stated on [JSR-338](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338), chapter 4.6.11, "*[a] null comparison expression tests whether or not the single-valued path expression or input parameter is a NULL value*", so it is not expected to support a filled list as an argument. To check lists, there is the "*IS [NOT] EMPTY*" expression, but it expects a *collection_valued_path_expression* and it is not your case.

I've stumbled sometimes with strange behavior of some persistence providers where they supported (anti-spec) this kind of comparison if you surround the parameter with parenthesis, but, again, you can not rely on it for future evolutions.

The best approach in your case would be define two different JPQLs or methods to deal with your both desired scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to make it inside a single query, but apparently I can't. I finally adapted my service implementation to query the proper method in my repository. 
I'm quite surprised to see it's impossible but it'll do the job anyway!